# How to prevent whitespace associated with items in the statusline from taking up space, when the item is not shown?

Tags: statusline

Consider the following `statusline` that makes use of `%r` to display `[RO]`, when `readonly` has been set.

The problem is that when `readonly` is not set, two spaces occur between `%f` (file path) and `%y` (file type). The problem is even worse, if I have several items, that may sometimes not be shown, separated by spaces.

Is there a way to completely remove an item from the `statusline`, when it's not shown, so that associated whitespace isn't shown?

```
set laststatus=2
set showcmd
set showmode

set statusline=%f
set statusline+=\ %r
set statusline+=\ %y
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's parentheses (aka "item group"). Sort of

```
let &statusline = '%f%( %r%)%( %y%)'
```

Some time ago I also wrote a [plugin](https://github.com/matveyt/vim-stalin) (actually a function) to assist in building status line expression from simple "blocks".

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a conditional:

```
set statusline+=%{&readonly?'\ [RO]':''}
```

This allows you to also change what is shown.  For example, I have:

```
set statusline+=%{&readonly?'\ !!':''}
```

Comment: How often is that conditional evaluated? I mean after which actions will the `statusline` be updated to reflect the current state?

Comment: I believe it’s after every key press. It’s certainly often enough for this use case. For example, I also have the current mode and line / column number displayed in mine which updates in real time.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to wrap more things in square-brackets, obviating the need for spaces (a modified version of what I start with):

```
let &statusline = '%([%f]%)%(%m%r%w%h%)%(%y%)'
```

Not all of the grouping is necessary, but I actually break my statusline out over multiple lines in my vimrc, so I just group everything. And there's this from `:help statusline`:

```
    When all items in a group becomes an empty string (i.e. flags that are
    not set) and a minwid is not set for the group, the whole group will
    become empty.  This will make a group like the following disappear
    completely from the statusline when none of the flags are set. >
        :set statusline=...%(\ [%M%R%H]%)...
```

Comment: I see. What are the square brackets used for? @Matt talks about item groups without the use of square brackets. And why does your example use `%(\ ...` for creating a space, when @Matt’s example doesn’t?

Comment: I use the square brackets literally for separating things visually (I also use colors, but that’s a separate deal). We both use parentheses for item groups. There is a difference between set and let; set requires spaces to be escaped, which I find annoying (hence let).